# How to programmatically change permissions on computer objects in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I've inherited control of an OU within an enterprise Active Directory domain. All of the computer objects in our OU are owned (and only writeable by) my predecessor. This prevents me from re-adding these computers unless I either delete the objects (in which case, the new objects will be owned by whatever account I add them with) or add write permissions of all of our OU admins. I want the later.

**So, I'm looking for a way to make a VBA/Powershell/other script which can be pointed to an OU and which can, for every computer object in that OU**:

- **Change the ownership of the object to a service/dept account we use**
- **Add write permissions on the object to include our OU admins group**

Actually, the VBA/Powershell preference is only because I'm figuring that this script might need to be run *on* one of the DC's, and I don't have control over what is installed on them. If it's possible to do this over the network with standard LDAP tools, then I guess any language will do.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't obtain priviledges you are not entitled to - you are delegated a role of 'OU Admin', which is probably a custom role in AD - the only option here is intervention of domain / enterprise admin who should recursively fix the permissions.